# Different result in Google indexed page statistics

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

My question is about Google indexed page statistics. I want to find out how many pages Google has indexed from my site. I use two ways:

1. type `site:mydomain.com` in Google search box.
2. View *Index Status* link from *Google Index* section in Google Webmaster Tools.

But both give me different result. Result from the first one is 123,000 and from the second one is 40,000!

Which one is correct?

Comment: When doing the 'site' search, go the 2nd page of results, the number should go down. The number on the first page is just an estimation.

Answer (score 1):

Your sitemap is probability old and missing new URLs.  Please try regenerating your sitemap and resubmit it for indexing again. The new URLs you are created are indexed by Google but as they are not available in the sitemap, which leads towards the discrepancy.

Consider the 123,000 as the correct number of URLS.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, the one in the search results is an estimation and the one in GWT is up to a week old. Like Simon said, click to the next page of the SERP's, it'll go down. For my site, I found that the number in GWT is usually closer to being the real number.